# binding blob storage to pdf in angularjs with syncfusion

Tags: angularjs, syncfusion

i am trying for a pdf viewer using syncfusion with input as a blob sorage url but CORS error is being thrown when i use it. my core is as follows

```
 blobService.getFileFromBlobByURI(objBlobStorageModel).then(function (result) {
        $scope.ShowprofileSpinner = false;
        $scope.serviceurl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(result.data);
        $scope.serverActionSettings = {
            load: 'LoadAction', fileUpload: 'FileUploadAction',
            download: 'DownloadAction'
        }
    });
```

and the html for pdf is as follows

```
 <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 680px" ej-pdfviewer e-serviceurl="serviceurl" e-serverActionSettings="serverActionSettings"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided details, we suspect that you are passing the PDF document data in the serviceURL. The serviceUrl property sets the Web Service Url not the PDF document data.  Refer to the below UG to display the PDF document using Web Service.

https://help.syncfusion.com/angularjs/pdfviewer/getting-started#displaying-pdf-document-using-web-api

If your requirement is to load the PDF document from blob storage, kindly refer to the below KB,
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8737/how-to-load-a-pdf-document-from-url-into-pdf-viewer-from-client-side

You can also load the PDF documents during the control initialization using the documentPath API. Refer to the “Load the documents during control initialization” section in the below link,
https://help.syncfusion.com/angularjs/pdfviewer/getting-started#initialize-and-configure-the-control

Regards,

Ramya T